# Neo4j - org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapperFactory

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-java-api

I am facing this weird error while creating GraphDB object in java.
My neo4j Version : 2.2.5

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException, ParseException {
    GraphDatabaseService graphdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabase(dbLocation);
    System.out.println("GraphDb started");
```

But, it is throwing the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.<init>(Lorg/neo4j/io/fs/FileSystemAbstraction;)V
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.<init>(ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.java:47)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.createPageCache(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:715)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.create(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:486)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:324)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:108)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:95)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:67)
at com.spnotes.kafka.Readlog.main(Readlog.java:26)
```

Earlier my code worked fine. Unable to figure the reason.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Simply looks like a packaging issue, in that you have jars for different versions/builds on the classpath